# React Navigation nested navigators best practices

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, stack-navigator

I am developing a basic mobile app and am split between two navigation design decisions:

1. tab navigator nested inside stack navigator
2. stack navigator nested inside tab navigator

The only difference I currently understand is that with 2 the tab bar is visible in all screens (is there any way to hide the tab bar in a nested screen), but with 1 the tab bar is only visible in the tab navigator screens.

I also know that with nested navigators, each navigator has it's own separate navigation history which seems desirable in 2 (I don't really understand how this would work with 1 though).

Is there anything I am missing that I should consider, or any best practices/common practices implemented by most apps?

Comment: I think you should put the stack navigator as the home navigator and then put the screens you want to use inside tab navigator inside the tab navigator and call it inside a component that is injected inside the root stack navigator , also you don't need the second stack navigator I geuss one is enough it can play the role for the second one

Answer (score 2):

structure

```
(stack navigator)| - screen 1 (initial screen)
                 | - screen 2
                 | - screen 3 (tab navigator) |
                                              |- screen 4 (initial screen) 
                                              |- screen 5
                                              |- screen 6 (an other stack) |
                                                                           |- screen 7 (initial)
                                                                           |- screen 8
```

Comment: but I think you could use just one stack , right?

Comment: Thanks for your response, however I have tried using this approach and have run into this error mentioned in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71900170/react-navigation-tab-screens-dont-show-up-as-separate-screens-in-history and am not sure how to resolve it